# Launching a Jekyll site from two computers (not simultaneously)

Tags: ruby, jekyll

My local jekyll site lives under `~/Dropbox/Sites/mysite/`.  I often make changes to the files from two different computers. Could I launch (one at a time) the `jekyll serve` function from each of these machines?

Is this possible and if yes, is it a bad idea? I just hate being restricted to one machine for maintaining my site.  Both machines have up to date versions of ruby and jekyll.

Answer (score 2):

I do this on my own Jekyll projects and it works perfectly. I can work on files on one machine, save everything, then switch to a second machine and pick up where I left off. I can run `jekyll serve` on both machines with no problem. I've never run `jekyll serve` on both machines at the same time, so I can't help there. But, running `jekyll serve` on either individual machine one-at-a-time works.

One issue I've run into in the past is when editing the same file on two different machines at the same time. Dropbox tried to save both versions and ended up with conflicting files (kinda like git merge conflicts). I haven't run into that when doing Jekyll stuff, just regular Word docs and such. But, lesson learned: don't try editing the same file from two different machines at the same time.

Comment: I was worried because when I tried this on machine #2, there was a prompt to execute ``bundle install``.  I thought this would create conflicts.  So I made a copy and tried and it works well.

Comment: `bundle install` installs ruby gems to the local computer in a different directory (`~/.gem/ruby/` I think). It shouldn't affect anything in Dropbox

Comment: Not at the moment (need a new Mac), but I have used my Jekyll installations, one on an iMac and one on my Win10 laptop to maintain the same sites. No problem at all.